# iOS: Scaling UIView -> touch input not working anymore

Tags: ios, touch, scaling

So, I have a game that was developed for iPad. It's pretty complex, combination of Unity and native UIKit, a bit of Interface builder, a lot of programmatic view generation, surely many hard-coding sins and so on.

Now I would like to create an iPhone version of this game. I could either go the lengths of redesigning and porting all the graphics, programmatically make them fit arbitrary view sizes and aspect ratios, use Interface builder's autolayout and so on,

OR

I just scale everything down to fit the screen. Which is what I'm trying now. I'm fine with letterboxing.

So, right after my application launched, I scale down the main window, like so:

```
//scale window down to iPhone 6 size
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.416666f, 0.416666f);
UIView* v = self.window;
CGPoint origin = v.frame.origin;
v.transform = transform;
v.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, v.frame.size.width, v.frame.size.height);
```

Works well, looks great, no aliasing or performance problems, but:

touch input doesn't work anymore - I can't click anything! Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for this and how to solve for it?

The same is true by the way If I replace 'self.window' with 'self.window.rootViewController.view'